# Query to get recursive records based on first ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I am trying to get the first spot for a given Lot, and how many other spots were refurbished to that first spot. My table is :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Spots](
[SpotID] [int] NOT NULL,
[LotID] [int] NULL,
[RefurbedSpotID] [int] NULL,
[datestamp] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Spots] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SpotID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (178, 5, 
NULL, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:41:50.833' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (183, 5, 
178, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:42:01.263' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (193, 5, 
183, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:43:03.527' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (212, 5, 
NULL, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:43:12.373' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (213, 5, 
193, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:43:19.023' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (380, 70, 
NULL, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:43:36.837' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (381, 70, 
380, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:43:43.637' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (382, 70, 
NULL, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:43:54.780' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (383, 70, 
381, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:44:06.390' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (384, 70, 
383, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:44:13.800' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (385, 71, 
NULL, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:46:17.660' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (389, 70, 
NULL, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:44:17.070' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (398, 71, 
NULL, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:46:26.670' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (465, 
101, NULL, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:46:44.450' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (491, 
118, NULL, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:48:32.380' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (1496, 
 118, 491, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:48:38.497' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (1497, 
118, NULL, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:48:42.617' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (1498, 
118, 1496, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:48:49.290' AS DateTime))
GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Spots] ([SpotID], [LotID], [RefurbedSpotID], [datestamp]) VALUES (1633, 
70, 382, CAST(N'2022-08-30T12:44:24.183' AS DateTime))
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Spots] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Spots_datestamp]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR 
[datestamp]
gO
```

This is the expected result. First SpotIDs are in brackets.

for LotID : 5

```
213, 193, 183,  [ 178 ]
```

for LotID : 70      x

```
384, 383, 381, [ 380 ]
```

for LotID : 71      x

```
[ 385 ]
```

for LotID : 101     x

```
[ 465 ]
```

for LotID : 118

```
1498, 1496,  [ 491 ]
```

What I tried was :

```
select *
from ( 
    select s2.spotID, s2.lotID , s2.RefurbedSpotID  
    from spots s2
    where s2.lotID = @lotID
    and s2.RefurbedSpotID is not null 

    union 

    select s1.spotID, s1.lotID, s1.RefurbedSpotID  
    from spots s1
    inner join ( select s2.spotID as s2_SpotID, s2.lotID as s2_lotID, s2.RefurbedSpotID 
as s2_RefurbedSpotID
                 from spots s2
                 where s2.lotID = @lotID ) s3 on s2_RefurbedSpotID = s1.spotID 
    where s1.lotID = @lotID 
    ) q
 order by spotID
```

However, I don't get the correct  results for LotIDs 70, 71, and 101. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the data, I can see what problems you have with lots 70 & 71. What is the expected result for lot 101? I'm only seeing one row with that LotID and so it seems to me that returning only 465 as the SpotID is the correct result.

Comment: Lot 101 should return 465. There is only one record.

Comment: 1633 wouldn't be included because it is based on 382. 382 is not the first SpotID for lot 70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You then need a recursive CTE for this. Start with the first row for each `LotId` and calculate a `Level` column along with the recursion.

Then you simply aggregate using `STRING_AGG` with a `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY` clause

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      s.SpotID,
      s.LotID,
      SpotIdString = CAST(CONCAT('[ ', s.SpotId, ' ]') AS varchar(30)),
      Level = 1
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.LotID ORDER BY s.datestamp)
        FROM Spots s
    ) s
    WHERE s.rn = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      s.SpotID,
      s.LotID,
      SpotIdString = CAST(s.SpotId AS varchar(30)),
      Level = cte.Level + 1
    FROM cte
    JOIN Spots s ON s.RefurbedSpotID = cte.SpotID AND s.LotID = cte.LotID
)
SELECT
  cte.LotID,
  STRING_AGG(SpotIdString, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cte.Level DESC)
FROM cte
GROUP BY
  cte.LotID;
```

Another option is to calculate the string during the recursion, and then just filter to the last one of the recursion using `ROW_NUMBER`

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      s.SpotID,
      s.LotID,
      SpotIdString = CAST(CONCAT('[ ', s.SpotId, ' ]') AS varchar(4000)),
      Level = 1
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.LotID ORDER BY s.datestamp)
        FROM Spots s
    ) s
    WHERE s.rn = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      s.SpotID,
      s.LotID,
      SpotIdString = CAST(CONCAT(s.SpotID, ', ', cte.SpotIdString) AS varchar(4000)),
      Level = cte.Level + 1
    FROM cte
    JOIN Spots s ON s.RefurbedSpotID = cte.SpotID AND s.LotID = cte.LotID
)
SELECT
  cte.LotID,
  cte.SpotIdString
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cte.LotID ORDER BY cte.Level DESC)
    FROM cte
) cte
WHERE cte.rn = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fca5427efdc2ece1d568e5963203ba57)

Comment: I am on SQL Server 2012. I am getting : 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: See second option. `STRING_AGG` is only available on 2016+